# "Nowhere near" at the end of a sentence

Tags: lyrics

I am struggling with a one line of lyrics. Can this line stand on it's own: "She knows she's nowhere near" - in a sense of nowhere near to change herself.

Comment: It's no different to, say, *She knows she can't* or *He hopes it isn't*. Pretty meaningless as a standalone utterance, but perfectly natural in the right context (that makes it obvious ***what*** she can't do, or he hopes isn't the case).

Answer (score 1):

It would be grammatical but pretty meaningless on its own.  You need context to understand what "nowhere near" means.  The context could be given in a preceding sentence or in a question to which this is the answer.

> Does Katy know how how far she is from passing the course?
>
> She knows she's nowhere near.

In context, Katy know that she is nowhere near the passing grade.

So the sentence can stand alone in prose grammatically, but it would be meaningless. As such it is like "She knows she can't" or "He hopes it isn't" (as the comment says).

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to song lyrics so the usual rules of grammar do not necessarily apply. In standard prose, the phrase would not stand alone. It would need to come after some other clause with a coordinating conjunction.

Comment: I don't agree. In context, it can stand alone. eg: A and B are watching football. A: "Goal! Yes! Oh no! He just missed!". B: "What do you mean 'He just missed'? That was nowhere near!"